# How to fix Konsole font?

Tags: rhel, kde, fonts, konsole, gvim

After updating to RHEL7 from RHEL6 my Konsole fonts are looking ugly and un-antialiased(Monospace size 11 in both systems). I played around with font antialiasing system settings but I am unable to make it identical to how it was before. Is there a way to restore the looks of font? i.e by copying some old font file or some settings from old system? Same issue is there for my Gvim.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issued after updating Debian 9 --> Debian 10.  In Konsole menu, select "Settings" --> "Edit Current Profile" --> "Appearance" tab --> "Select Font" and try different fonts.